# Do we distinguish between row and column vectors when speaking of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vectors

Another question I feel silly for asking: I know that row- and col-vector spaces will be isomorphic, but is it conventional to distinguish between them?

eg if we want to refer to the row-space of the 2x2 identity matrix, are the sets $$\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \, \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \right\}$$
and
$$ \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \, \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \right\}$$
considered equivalent?

Thanks in advance for your time and assistance.

Comment: I try to think of row vectors as real linear *functions* that act on vectors.

Comment: One is a subset of $\mathbb R^{1 \times 2}$ and the other of $\mathbb R^{2 \times 1}$.  I would regard the first as the row space.  But some people might regard them as in a sense *equivalent modulo transpose*